# How do I let the compiler know which virtual to use from the imported library?

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-c++

I am getting a `call of overloaded 'connect(IPAddress, int)' is ambiguous` error when using the [`<ArduinoMqttClient.h>`](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoMqttClient) library. This only happens when I use an IP address instead of a host.

I am working on writing some code to connect to an MQTT broker running on AWS. When I use the host name, I am unable to create a secure connection but when I use the IP address of the service this problem goes away. The sample code I have modified originally implemented the host name version of the [`connect`](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoMqttClient/blob/cd59ba1f3c3ef41d52bf0042df707287529662c1/src/MqttClient.h#L69) call but since I need to use an IP address, I am running into this issue.

```cpp
#include <ArduinoMqttClient.h>
#include <WiFi101.h>

const char ssid[] = "ssid";
const char pass[] = "password";
IPAddress broker(x, x, x, x);

WiFiSSLClient    wifiSSLClient;
MqttClient    mqttClient(wifiSSLClient);

unsigned long lastMillis = 0;

void loop() {
  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    connectWiFi();
  }

  if (!mqttClient.connected()) {
    // MQTT client is disconnected, connect
    connectMQTT();
  }

  // poll for new MQTT messages and send keep alives
  mqttClient.poll();

  // publish a message roughly every 5 seconds.
  if (millis() - lastMillis > 5000) {
    lastMillis = millis();

    publishMessage();
  }
}

unsigned long getTime() {
  // get the current time from the WiFi module  
  return WiFi.getTime();
}

void connectWiFi() {
  Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
  Serial.print(ssid);
  Serial.print(" ");

  while (WiFi.begin(ssid, pass) != WL_CONNECTED) {
    // failed, retry
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(5000);
  }
  Serial.println();

  Serial.println("You're connected to the network");
  Serial.println();
}

void connectMQTT() {
  Serial.print("Attempting connection to MQTT broker: ");
  Serial.print(broker);
  Serial.println(" ");
  mqttClient.setUsernamePassword("username", "password");

  while (!mqttClient.connect(broker, 8883)) { // <-- this is where the error is being thrown
    // failed, retry
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(5000);
  }
  Serial.println();

  Serial.println("You're connected to the MQTT broker");
  Serial.println();

  // subscribe to a topic
  mqttClient.subscribe("arduino/incoming");
}
```

Ideally it would accept the parameters but I am getting the following error:

```
   virtual int connect(const IPAddress& ip, uint16_t port) { }; /* ESP8266 core defines this pure virtual in Client.h */

               ^~~~~~~

exit status 1
call of overloaded 'connect(IPAddress&, int)' is ambiguous
```

Comment: remove the lline from MqttClient.h

Comment: I'm not sure I can do that because I don't own that library. I am simply importing it by adding `#include <ArduinoMqttClient.h>` to my file.

Comment: then use esp8266 core 2.5.0 https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoMqttClient/commit/ade2940a2ffe1cdc04e39d638d28378cc2c41c32#commitcomment-35808474

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and helping out :) I'm still fairly new to the Arduino and micro-controller world. Does that library with any Arduino board? I am currently using the MRK1000.

Comment: sorry, then no 2.5.0. use 0.1.3 version of the Mqtt library